# Why is my receptacle tester not showing a complete lack of ground?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

I've been using a receptacle tester which shows me that my outlets are perfect as far as it can tell. Yet I know for a fact that ground is completely missing from many of the receptacles I've tested. Sometimes the ground wire is wired but it connects to old cloth wiring with only two wires and the ground is just capped off not touching anything, and sometimes the outlet is in a plastic box with absolutely no ground anywhere. My tester still reports that everything is fine.

[image: One example. In this one I had to dig the ground wires out for the photo because they were clipped short and buried under the plastic sheathing]

One example. In this one I had to dig the ground wires out for the photo because they were clipped short and buried under the plastic sheathing.

In the photo above not only are the ground wires not touching anything but inspecting from the other side of the wall I verified that the metal enclosure is not touching anything except wood drywall and insulation bats. The other examples are similarly clear that ground is not attained.

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing all the wires going to one of these "I think it is open ground" receptacles? Are the wires coming in to the boxes: wires inside conduit, non-metallic cable, armored cable?

Comment: Are your boxes metal? What kind of house stucco? Some metal boxes were grounded from the outside some in stucco are grounded by touching the wire or mesh in stucco as a possible reason.

Comment: Ed, some are metal, some are plastic. Not plaster walls, drywall.

Comment: Pictures would also show if neutral is connected to ground on the receptacle - that shouldn't be, but sometimes is...

Comment: I have zero confidence that things were done the right way in this house, so if there's another possibility that would make my tester show "wires correct" even if it's wrong, that's probably it.

Comment: Is it the metal boxes that are showing as grounded? It is possible the home was built in the 60’s prior to the grounding requirements and the copper just happens to be touching the metal box.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the metal boxes showing as grounded. It's an outlet tester. The outlet ground may be electrically connected to the box, but the box itself is not grounded.